# Web scraping on stock market - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, attributeerror, nonetype

[View the picture for the website code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p57nW.png)
I am trying to do web scraping on stock market websites.

**My code is:**

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import * soup=BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND"))
title = soup.title.text
name = soup.find('span', {'class': 'navi-bar__logo--title'}).text #this class is executed
value = soup.find('span', {'class': 'priceText__1853e8a5'}).text #problem is with this class
print(name)
print(value)
```

I'm currently stuck on this **error**:

> Warning (from warnings module): File "C:\Users\bakkolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py", line 181 markup_type=markup_type))
>
> UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser").
>
> This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.
>
> The code that caused this warning is on line 1 of the file . To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:
>
> BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})
>   To this:
>
> BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html.parser")
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\bakkolla\Desktop\ex.py", line 8, in 
>   value = soup.find('span', {'class': 'priceText__1853e8a5'}).text #problem is with this class
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful soup cannot find a class named priceText__1853e8a5 so it returned None, hence cannot get the text property of none.
Check with a few pages if the div class doesn't change with page and check if you spelt correctly

Comment: There is a class with that class-name(view the image) even after that it is returning none/. Why is it so ?

Comment: Reload the page to see if the class names remains same, check with a few more pages. Whatever it is, that error message implies that beautifulsoup cannot locate that class

Comment: Class name is not changing. Yeah it is not locating that's why i raised the question here.